# How to align equations in the equation environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have been looking on how to align equations and I have seen numerous examples with `\align` and `\flalign`, however whenever I try to use these in the `equation` environment, I get an error. I would like to be able to align the equations at the middle equal signs.

Here is an image of the current output:
[image: current output]

```
\begin{proof}
Let   \begin{math} \varepsilon > 0 \end{math} be given and let \begin{math} \delta = \varepsilon \end{math}. It follows that for  \begin{math} I:(X,d^*) \to (R,d) \end{math}

\begin{equation*}
\text{if}\quad\d^*(f,g) = \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta 
\end{equation*} 

\begin{equation*}
\text{then}\quad{\bigg  | \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t  \bigg  |  =  \bigg  | \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |\leq
\end{equation*} 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \bigg  | {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta = \varepsilon
\end{equation*}     
\end{proof}
```

I am now using `aligned` instead of the `equation` environment. Here is the code and the error I'm getting:

CODE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Prb1}{Problem}

\begin{Prb1}
 Since the the integral is nothing more that an infinite sum it obeys the triangle inequality. Hence, we may use this property to prove that \begin{math}I:(X,d^*) \to (R,d) \end{math} is continuous. Where \begin{math} d^*(f,g) = \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t\end{math} for continuous functions \begin{math}f,g,\end{math} and \begin{math}I(f) = \int_a^b f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \end{math} \hfill
\end{Prb1}

\begin{proof}

Let   \begin{math} \varepsilon > 0 \end{math} be given and let \begin{math} \delta = \varepsilon \end{math}. It follows that for  \begin{math} I:(X,d^*) \to (R,d) \end{math}

\begin{align*}
\text{if}\quad\d^*(f,g) &= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta \\
\text{then}\quad{\bigg  | \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t  \bigg  |  &=  \bigg  | \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |\leq \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \bigg  | {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |&= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta = \varepsilon  \end{align*} 
\begin{equation*}
\text{if}\quad\ d^*(f,g) = \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta \end{equation*} 

\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

ERROR:

```
))))
Runaway argument?
 \text {if}\quad \d ^*(f,g) &= \int _a^b \bigg |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.25 

?
```

Comment: you need to `\usepackage{amsmath}` to define align note it is an environment `\begin{align}...\end{align}` not a command `\alsign{...}` it starts math mode itself so you do not place it inside an equation environment.

Comment: There's an extra `{` between `\quad` and `\bigg` in the second line of the align, just remove that
.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code you present.  Below is one rewriting that fixes several points followed by some discussion.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Let \begin{math} \varepsilon > 0 \end{math} be given and
  let \begin{math} \delta = \varepsilon \end{math}. It follows that
  for \begin{math} I\colon (X,d^*) \to (R,d) \end{math} if
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}^*(f,g) = \int_a^b \bigl|f(t) - g(t)\bigr|\, \mathrm{d}t <
  \delta
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{multline*}
  \biggl| \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \biggr|
  = \biggl| \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg| \\
  \leq
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \bigl| {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})}
  \bigr|
  = \int_a^b \bigl|f(t) - g(t)\big|\, \mathrm{d}t < \delta = \varepsilon.
\end{multline*}
\end{proof}

Alternatively we may write the last display as:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    \biggl| \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \biggr|
    &= \biggl| \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg| \\
    &\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigl| {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})}
    \bigr| = \int_a^b \bigl|f(t) - g(t)\big|\, \mathrm{d}t < \delta =
    \varepsilon.
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

As pointed out by the others `align` is a top level environment that replaces `equation`.  It has a version that can be used inside `equation`, namely `aligned`.  However, I would not use this in the above situation.

Usually, one would regard the text parts `if` and `then` as not part of the equation (although there are circumstances where one might want to include them in the equation for emphasising a special point).  I would thus move them into the main text, and then you have a short equation separated by `then` from a long equation.  The long equation can be either set with `multline` (first line shoved left, second line shoved right), or aligned with the `split` environment.  Both versions are shown above.  Note that I am used to splitting lines before relations such as `\leq` (different countries have some different traditions here).

Now your code contained a `\d` which was undefined.  I guessed this was meant to be a `\mathrm d`, and changed it accordingly.

For the absolute values, you should tell LaTeX which is a left delimiter and which is a right delimiter, so use `\bigl` and `\bigr` and their vairiants instead of just `\big` (or `\left...\right`.  The placing of these delimiters in relation to the integrals was mathematically incorrect; I have moved them to a position that can make sense.  I have also made some of them smaller than you specified.

Finally, for the map `I` the following colon should be typeset with `\colon` for correct spacing.  Incidentally, this map is not used in the connected sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your response contains a lot of great pointers for a beginner such as myself. Again, thanks a lot. (I would vote you up, but I cannot yet.)

Comment: if `amsthm` is providing the `proof` environment, at the end of the equation, if there is room on the right for the "tombstone", placing `\qedhere` will move it up to the end of the display, aligning it vertically on the baseline of the last line, if the display is coded with `align*`, or on the common baseline if a "subsidiary" environment (e.g. `aligned`) is used.  usually, `align*` will give a more pleasing result.

Answer (score 5):

Environments like `align` (from the `amsmath` package) are meant to be used instead of `equation`, not inside of it.

If you really want to use it inside of an equation, you should use the `aligned` environment instead.

```
\begin{align*}
\text{if}\quad d^*(f,g) &= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta  \\
\text{then}\quad\bigg  | \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t  \bigg  |  &=  \bigg  | \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |\leq \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \bigg  | {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |&= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Other version (the spacing will be different, and if you need numbering, you should be careful):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\text{if}\quad d^*(f,g) &= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta  \\
\text{then}\quad\bigg  | \int_a^b f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t  \bigg  |  &=  \bigg  | \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |\leq \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \bigg  | {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})} \bigg  |&= \int_a^b \bigg  |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \  \bigg  | < \delta = \varepsilon
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: When I try the first suggestion I get this error:
Runaway argument?
 \text {if}\quad \d ^*(f,g) &= \int _a^b \bigg |f(t) - g(t)\, \mathrm \ETC.


I will past the entire code in the question
! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.25

Comment: @Eric: I editted and now it compiles. I had to remove a brace after a `\quad` (probably an error) and replace a `\d` by `d` (either an error or a command you redefined and forgot to include in your MWE).